# deleted kube-prometheus-stack alertmanager CRD and can not install alertmanager

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kube-prometheus-stack

im new to helm here.
So i was using helm kube-prometheus-stack version 36.x, and saw that the newest version  has a native telegram config for alertmanager instead of using another client-side telegram webhook.

What i did was updated the alertmanager value configuration in the value file. Then I ran the migrated for alertmanager CRD from 35.x to 36.x with the followings:

```
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.57.0/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagerconfigs.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.57.0/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagers.yaml
```

Then 38.x to 39.x ( yes, i did ignore the From 37.x to 38.x and From 36.x to 37.x in the [doc][1]

```
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.58.0/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagerconfigs.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.58.0/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagers.yaml
```

And then helm upgrade --install my_chart_name prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -f my_value_file.yaml but the alert manager did not update the telegram_configs in alertmanager. So i manually deleted the both two alertmanager CRD "alertmanagerconfigs.monitoring.coreos.com" & "alertmanagers.monitoring.coreos.com".
After that I ran the two latest migration scripts for alertmanger CRD like the above

```
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.58.0/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagerconfigs.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.58.0/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagers.yaml
```

I ran the helm upgrade --install my_chart_name prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -f my_value_file.yaml but this time, the alertmanager pod and statefulset are deleted and could not recreate. How can I fix this and also do the migration to the newversion correctly without deleting my current helm kube-prometheus-stack installation? even though i ran the migration scripts. Thank you.

EDIT: turned out i was stupid, the telegram_configs is wrong format, and thats why it can not create a new statefulset/pod config for alertmanager. Solved, sorry guys
[1]: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack#from-36-x-to-37-x

Answer (score -1):

turned out i was stupid, the telegram_configs is wrong format, and thats why it can not create a new statefulset/pod config for alertmanager. Solved, sorry guys